# What sort of encryption is used?

Tags: encryption

What encryption is used in a default Ubuntu full hard drive encryption and is it possible to specify another?

Answer (score 1):

Probably AES256 (as I could figure out from https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EncryptedHome)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it uses an XTS-AES (AES-cipher) with a hash algorithm sha1 (256bit key-size) by default, using Linux Unified Key Setup (LUKS). You should be able to change this manually somewhere in the Ubiquity scripts, when the command *cryptsetup* is used.

Type in `man cryptsetup` for more information.